# How to say you go first in German

Tags: phrase-request, politeness

I have seen a lot of people who don't buy a lot of things from the supermarket and usually I am in front of them queue. I want to know how to say you can go to the cashier before me in German.

Comment: Easiest: *Bitte* + hand gesture

Comment: @CarstenS No, *Bitte, nach Ihnen*

Comment: @adjan, definitiv eleganter!

Answer (score 14):

Formal possibilities:

> *Gehen Sie ruhig vor.* (as an offer)
>   *Sie können gerne vorgehen.* (as an offer)
>   *Nach Ihnen.* (as an offer)
>   *Möchten Sie vorgehen?* (as a question)

Informal possibilities:

> *Geh ruhig vor.* (as an offer)
>   *Du kannst gerne vorgehen.* (as an offer)
>   *Nach dir.* (as an offer)
>   *Möchtest du vorgehen?* (as a question)

Comment: 'Du' is not only for persons which you know

Comment: @Iris: I know Angela Merkel... kind of...

Comment: @Iris, you are right, I fixed it.

Comment: The very common *Nach Ihnen* is not part of this list

Comment: _Nach Ihnen_ is used out of special situations (e.g. you arrive both at the same time). **The other formal solutions are good**. The informal versions should only be used for friends, otherwise it would be very impolite.

Comment: @JepZ Correct remark about "Nach Ihnen". It's typically used by a gentleman (or a clerk with a customer) at an entrance.

Comment: @JepZ The "Du" or "Sie" issue is a difficult one. I wouldn't say it's *very* impolite; it may just be missing the proper tone, but when said with a smile will rarely be taken as an offense. General criteria for "Sie" are higher age, higher social position, more formal clothes, formal event. Using "Du" can be a compliment since it expresses that one feels comfortable with the other. People whose socialization was after the 1950s are more likely to use it; it can signify that you see the other one as modern, too.

Comment: Sure, "Du" is not only for persons which you know in general, but in this particular case (an obvious foreigner talking in a shop), the formal "Sie" is the appropriate version unless the other person is a child or young adolescent (school age, visibly up to 17-18 years).

Comment: Since the question mentioned cashiers specifically: I hear _Gehen Sie ruhig vor._ multiple times a day on the register, the others almost never. They are also good and valid, but in my experience not used in this particular situation.

Answer (score 7):

A pretty common (formal) phrase is (with either the *bitte* in front or at the end)

> Bitte, nach Ihnen.

or just

> Nach Ihnen.

One can also say the less formal

> Nach dir.